# HapMap 3 phased haplotype

Tags: human-genetics

I need to get HapMap 3 phased haplotype data. Where can I find it?

Actually I need these data for specific populations and a specific gene. What is the easiest way to find data?

I hope I can find an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/hapmap/) is the FTP address. Inside you will find the phase_3 folder. For other questions check [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/variation/news/NCBI_retiring_HapMap/) page (the link to the HelpDesk is at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I used following command for this file tar -jxf hapmap3_r1_b36_fwd.qc.poly.tar.bz2 . But I don't know how can I get haplotype data for ± 1 Mb at LCT gene from this file. Actually I need a data file which include sample ID and alleles to use in R.

Comment: That is another question and it is a bioinformatic one, maybe StackOverflow or Biostars are more suitable for that.